# How to swap the dropdown values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have two dropdowns (i.e. one dropdown with minimal values and another with maximum values). If I select a value in first dropdown with greater value than the second dropdown, it has to be swapped. But I used normal swap method, it is only working for input boxes.

Here is my custom dropdown code:

**HTML**:

```
  <div  class="dropdown">
     <ul>
       <li class="prfdwn" data-value="value" ng-repeat="value in data" ng-
        click="setMaxVal(val)" ng-blur="swap()">{{value.txt}}</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 <div class="dropdown">
   <ul>
      <li class="prfdwn" data-value="value" ng-repeat="value in data" ng-
      click="setMinVal(val)" ng-blur="swap()">{{value.txt}}</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

**JS**:

```
$scope.data = [{
"id": 1,
"txt": 1,
 },
{
"id": 2,
"txt": 2,
},
{
"id": 3,
"txt": 3,
},
 {
 "id": 4,
"txt": 4,
 },
 {
"id": 5,
"txt": 5,
}];

   vm.swap = function () {
    if (vm.minVal != "" && vm.minVal != undefined && vm.maxVal != "" && 
  vm.maxVal  != undefined) {
        if (vm.minVal > vm.maxVal ) {
            var tempVal = vm.minVal;
            vm.minVal = vm.maxVal ;
            vm.maxVal  = tempVal;
        }

    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The `blur` event is not going to happen on an `li` element, since by default it doesn't get focus. You might want to move your `ng-click` and `ng-blur` to an anchor element nested within the `li`.

Comment: @ Mike McCaughan Can you please explain clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello_ friend,

I made a sample code snippet where the actual swap is made into the `setVal` function.

In your code snippet this `ng-click="setMinVal(val)"` I think should be `ng-click="setMinVal(value)"`.

Anyway check if this code snippet will help you to do what you want. If you want to change the behaviour you can do it inside `setVal` function.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('AppController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.minValue = '';
  $scope.maxValue = '';
  $scope.swapText = '';

  $scope.setVal = function(value, dropdownFlag) {

    // here you can change with what propery of the object you are working
    var val = value.txt;

    if (dropdownFlag == 1) {
      // coming from minValue dropdown
      if ($scope.maxValue >= val) {
        $scope.minValue = val;
      } else if ($scope.maxValue == '') {
        // max value is still not set so we can set the min value
        $scope.minValue = val;
      } else {
        // seems that maxValue is less than selected value - swap them
        $scope.minValue = $scope.maxValue;
        $scope.maxValue = val;
        showSwapText();
      }
    } else {
      // coming from maxValue dropdown
      if ($scope.minValue > val) {
        // minValue is greater that selected value then swap
        $scope.maxValue = $scope.minValue;
        $scope.minValue = val;
        showSwapText();
      } else {
        // seems that maxValue is less than selected value - swap them
        $scope.maxValue = val;
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.data = [{
      "id": 1,
      "txt": 1,
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "txt": 2,
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "txt": 3,
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "txt": 4,
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "txt": 5,
    }
  ];

  function showSwapText() {
    $scope.swapText = 'SWAPPED!';
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.swapText = '';
    }, 1000);
  }

}]);
```

```css
.dropdown{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppController">

  <h2>Min Value is {{ minValue }}</h2>
  <h2>Max Value is {{ maxValue }}</h2>
  <h2 style="position: fixed;top: 0;left: 200px;">{{ swapText }}</h2>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Min</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="prfdwn" data-value="value" ng-repeat="value in data" ng-click="setVal(value, 1)">{{value.txt}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Max</span>
    <ul>
      <li class="prfdwn" data-value="value" ng-repeat="value in data" ng-click="setVal(value, 2)">{{value.txt}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi friend for this kind of text in response ,how to check greater the condition(i;e{val:1,txt:"4 feet 1 inches or 124.46cm"}).here you have given in the setVal(value,1),how to do this for text.

Comment: @bpbsr well if you know that **val** property of your object is representing the strength of this pair then you can use  `var val = value.val;` instead of `var val = value.txt;` inside `setVal` function, otherwise you can use a `regex` to parse the **txt** property and get the desired value that you need for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

An `li` element does not receive focus, and therefore the `blur` event will never fire. A small change in the HTML structure could help:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li class="prfdwn" data-value="value" ng-repeat="value in data">
      <a ng-click="setMaxVal(val)" ng-blur="swap()">{{value.txt}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li class="prfdwn" data-value="value" ng-repeat="value in data">
      <a ng-click="setMaxVal(val)" ng-blur="swap()">{{value.txt}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`a` elements do receive focus, and the `blur` event will fire on them.

Now, that's treating the symptom. You might want to rethink how you're structuring your HTML (perhaps with two `<select>` elements), but this should fix your immediate problem.